# Banks suggestions in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, banking

I'll be working in the Netherlands, I want to open a bank account there. Id like to ask you for banks suggestions please .

Having an English version for the online bank website is a critical issue for me because I've been living in Portugal for two years and I have a Santander Totta account, which is not the same as Santander, but they don't have anything in English. I struggled a lot to learn how to deal with complex operations in Portuguese.

And would your suggestions be different if I put the language thing aside ?

Comment: I use ING which doesn't have English version for the website but the mobile app is localised. And in a case of really not understanding I use chrome translate plugin. But if you really want to have proper English interface than I believe ABN Amro is only one choice. However my experience with ABN Amro service is not perfect and to be honest sometimes I have difficulties with ING as well

Answer (score 2):

I have an account with ABN-AMRO. I can't really compare them to any other banks, but they do have most of everything in English, including their website(s), and I've never had trouble getting help in English.

In Amsterdam, I think they have a reasonable spread of branches.

On the other hand I feel I'm getting shafted with the annual credit card usage fee, but: 1. You don't have to get one if you have a credit card from your state of origin and a local debit card, and 2. It's possible that this high fee is the same elsewhere.

About other issues - interest rates on savings and loans, international transaction speed etc. - again I can't comment since I have nothing to compare against.

Comment: You can compare them at independer https://www.independer.nl/spaarrekening/intro.aspx